# How to dynamically add rows with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Imagine you have a tkinter program and want to add some widget without changing all the rows how can I accomplish that?

Here is the program:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Hello Everyone.")
window.geometry("400x400")


window.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)
window.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)


coordinaten = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0],
               [2, 1], [2, 2]]

for i in range(len(coordinaten)):
    button = Button(window)
    button.grid(row=coordinaten[i][0], column=coordinaten[i][1], sticky="ewns")


window.mainloop()
```

Imagine you want to add a label to the window. Is there way to this without changing all the values of the rows like this:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Hello Everyone.")
window.geometry("400x400")


window.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)
window.grid_rowconfigure((1, 2, 3), weight=2)
window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


label = Label(window, text="Some text", bg="green")
label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, sticky="ewns")

coordinaten = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0],
               [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2]]

for i in range(len(coordinaten)):
    button = Button(window)
    button.grid(row=coordinaten[i][0], column=coordinaten[i][1], sticky="ewns")


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you asking about adding a row at the end, or _inserting_ a row between two existing rows?

Comment: Insert a row, for instance you have write a program with 100 widgets and you want to add a widget in position 50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: dynamically add rows python tkinter?

***Is there way to this without changing all the values of the rows?***
Don't use predefined Row/Columns, here `coordinaten = ...`, at all.

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        def command():
            pass

        buttons = (('button text 1.1', command), ('button text 1.2', command), ('button text 1,3', command),
                   ('button text 2.1', command), ('button text 2.2', command), ('button text 2.3', command),
                   ('button text 3.1', command), ('button text 3.2', command), ('button text 3.3', command)
                   )

        tk.Label(text='label text').grid(row=0, columnspan=3, sticky="ewns")

        # Button Layout X x 3
        row_offset = 1
        column_n = 3
        for row in range(row_offset, (len(buttons) // column_n) + row_offset):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=2)

            for column in range(column_n):
                self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)

                # The left side has to be in sync with the `button` tuple  
                text, command = buttons[((row - row_offset) * column_n) + column]

                btn = tk.Button(self, text=text, command=command)
                btn.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="ewns")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

To insert a new Row of Buttons, do:

```
        buttons = (('button text 1.1', command), ('button text 1.2', command), ('button text 1,3', command),
                   ('button text 2.1', command), ('button text 2.2', command), ('button text 2.3', command),
                   ('button new 2.1.1', command), ('button new 2.2.1', command), ('button new 2.3.1', command),
                   ('button text 3.1', command), ('button text 3.2', command), ('button text 3.3', command)
                   )
```